# How do you choose what type of blimp you get sent?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v

According to the GTA Wiki, in GTA V's Enhanced Edition you can order an [Atomic Blimp](https://gta.fandom.com/wiki/Atomic_Blimp) or [Xero Blimp](https://gta.fandom.com/wiki/Xero_Blimp) from your phone's contact menu. However, when I looked up [a video calling the blimp](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5uaWtLIFgDA) I didn't see any way to choose what type of blimp you get sent.

How do you choose whether you get sent an Atomic Blimp or a Xero Blimp when you call the Blimp contact?

Answer (score 1):

It appears that normal players will receive the Atomic blimp.
You must be a returning player in order to get the Xero blimp, in that case calling the Blimp in your contacts will give you a Xero one.

By the way this is a bit bugged, as many eligible players can't get the Xero.

Comment: What counts as a returning player?

Comment: According to Reddit: "players who previously owned the PS/XBox 360 version and also purchased the PS4, XBOne, or PC versions that were released in 2015". I think this is tied to the Rockstar account.